# CS50 helpers.c, Code not finding value (needle)? Any ideas?

Tags: c, cs50

Not sure why it cant find the value in the array. Whenever I run the code it returns "didn't find the needle in the haystack."

```
 /**
 * helpers.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Helper functions for Problem Set 3.
 */

#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"


/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    //Makes sure the input value is positive

    while (n > 0)
   {
    //Searches until value is found

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (value == values[i])
        {
            printf("Found it!\n");
            return true;
        }

    }

  }

  return false;

}
```

Haven't started sort

```
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
/*void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    return;
}*/
```

I have changed it and used an if statement the way it was, still gives the same.

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"


/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{

  /*  if (n >= 0)
   {
    return false; 
   }*/


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (value == values[i])
        {
            printf("Found it!\n");
            return true;
        }

    }
return false;


}
```

Problem solved!It seems I accidentally made a second file with the same name outside the folder. I was changing the wrong file!!!

Comment: What is input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: ***Returns a 1 if its not found, return false;***, really?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this part:

```
while (n > 0)
```

Which puts you in an endless loop.
You should replace it with an if statement:

```
if(n<=0){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I removed it just to be safe. Still the needle cant be found.

Comment: well seems ok actually... can you put printf(values[i]); before the if (value == values[i]) statement and see what do you get as output?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check if `n` is positive. The `for` loop does that already. When you write a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

the first thing that happens is that variable `i` is set to `0`. The second thing that happens is that `i` is compared to `n`. If `n` is a negative number, then `i` won't be less than `n`, so the loop body will never run.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Makes sure the input value is positive
// Okay donot loop  just return, not sure how you deal with zero though
if (n < 0)
    return false;
```